# If condition not working in android intent activity

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I need to start a new intent activity based on if condition, but
the if condition is not working, but the value gets printed in the log file.

the code that I use is given below:

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageButton next2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        next2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText pin =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); //value from edit text

                Log.v("EditText", pin.getText().toString()); //this works in log

                if (pin.equals(0000)){
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), home.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing `pin` which is the `EditText` and *not* the string to `0000` which is not a string either. You want:

```
if (pin.getText().toString().equals("0000")) {
```

Comment: thank you for your immediate response.. got the problem solved with your help... thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the condition:
    if(pin.equals(0000))

Basically you are testing:
    if(pin.equals(SOME_CONSTANT))

What you want is:
    if(pin.getText().equals("0000"))

Comment: The `getText()` method of an `EditText` returns an `Editable` and not a `String`. You need to use `getText().toString()` in this case.